# execution of task in java within specified time

Tags: java, arraylist, delay

I want to execute few lines of code with 5ms in Java. Below is the snippet of my code:

```
public void delay(ArrayList<Double> delay_array, int counter_main) {
    long start=System.currentTimeMillis();
        ArrayList<Double> delay5msecs=new ArrayList<Double>();
    int index1=0, i1=0;

    while(System.currentTimeMillis() - start <= 5)
    {
        delay5msecs.add(i1,null);
        //System.out.println("time");
        i1++;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<counter_main-1;i++) {
        if(delay5msecs.get(i)!=null) {
            double x1=delay_array.get(i-index1);
            delay5msecs.add(i,x1);
            //System.out.println(i);
        } else {
            index1++;
            System.out.println("index is :"+index1);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that the entire array is getting filled with null values and I am getting some exceptions related to index as well. Basically, I want to fill my array list with 0 till 5ms and post that fill the data from another array list in it. I've not done coding since a long time. Appreciate your help. 
Thank You.

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace in your question ?

Comment: I am sorry but what would that be?

Comment: **I am getting some exceptions related to index as well.** the error which you said

Comment: I am not sure if I have used the correct way to assign "0/null" to first few elements till 5ms. Could you please check if the logic is correct. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` will probably not have the resolution you need for 5ms. The granularity on Windows may not be better than 15ms anyway, so your code will be very platform sensitive, and may actually not do what you want.

The resolution you need might be doable with `System.nanoTime()` but, again, there are platform limitations you might have to research. I recall that you can't just scale the value you get and have it work everywhere.

If you can guarantee no other threads running this code, then I suppose a naive loop and fill will work, without having to implement a worker thread that waits for the filler thread to finish.

You should try to use the Collection utilities and for-each loops instead of doing all this index math in the second part.

I suppose I should also warn you that nothing in a regular JVM is guaranteed to be real-time. So if you need a *hard*, dependable, reproducible 5ms you might be out of luck.

Comment: can you please suggest how would a loop guarantee an approximate interval of 5ms. a pseudo code would do, thank you!